# Google app script - installed add-on is not visible in the email

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons

1. I have published the add-on domain wide
2. installed the add-on from one of my domain gmail account
3. it installed successfully
4. but, when I go to the email details, it is not showing that add-on option

what might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue by enabling exceptionLogging in the add-on manifest. Add-on is failing with error while connecting to my server.

**How I track down the issue?**

In add-on manifest we can set exceptionLogging to STACKDRIVER, which will enable logs in stackdriver. After enabling, try to load your add-on and check the logs from add-on script editor > View > Stackdrive logging